# javascript изменение функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, есть небольшой код

```
repl = {
    b: `**`,
    u: `__`,
    strike: `--`,
}
text = text.replace(/<[/]{0,1}(b|u|strike)>/g, (match, p1) => {
    return repl[p1];
});
return text;
```

но дело в том что староватые браузеры выдают ошибку

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

Видимо из-за знака `=>`, подскажите пожалуйста как можно изменить эту функцию чтобы принцып работы оставался таким же, но в синтаксисе не было этого знака

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (match, p1) => {
> ```

```
function (match, p1) {
```